# starting monkeyrunner but only jyphon starts

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

please can someone help i have not done this for a while. I am trying to execute a monkeyrunner python script. In my c:\Android\sdk\tools\bin directory i run the following: monkeyrunner monkeyRun.py. Nothing happen only jython command line starts

Answer (score 0):

Passing the script file to the monkeyrunner is the right thing to do, see https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html.

> If you provide a filename as an argument, the monkeyrunner command runs the file's contents as a Python program; **otherwise, it starts an interactive session**.